# Delete object from ArrayList of objects and ListView using Intent

Tags: android, listview, android-intent

I have a list of exercises. When you click on one exercise, the exercise's details appears (infos from sqlite, communication using intent). There is also a button for deleting exercise and here is my problem, how can I delete exercise using that button?

Here is some code that may be useful to solve my problem. I tried to send my ID to ListDetails and then on clicking button send it back to ListExercisesFragment:

**ListExercisesFragment class**

```
 private ArrayList<Exercise> lExercise=new ArrayList<Exercise>();
    private CustomListAdapter dataAdapter;
    private static  final int REQUEST_CODE=100;
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){
               public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent,View view,int position,long id){
                   Exercise exercise=(Exercise) listView.getItemAtPosition(position);                
                   Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(),ListDetail.class);
                   intent.putExtra("id",exercise.getId());
                   intent.putExtra("name",exercise.getName());
                   intent.putExtra("series",exercise.getSeries());
                   intent.putExtra("reps",exercise.getReps());
                   intent.putExtra("weights",exercise.getWeights());
                   intent.putExtra("notes",exercise.getNotes());
                   startActivityForResult(intent,REQUEST_CODE);

               }
       });
@Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode,int resultCode,Intent data){
        if(requestCode==REQUEST_CODE){
            if(resultCode==getActivity().RESULT_OK){
                long id=data.getLongExtra("id",-1);
                if(id!=-1){
                    deleteExerciseWithID(id);
                }
            }
        }

        super.onActivityResult(requestCode,resultCode,data);
    }


    private void deleteExerciseWithID(long id){
        for(Exercise e:lExercise){
            if( e.getId()==id ){
                dbHelper.deleteRowWithId(id);
                lExercise.remove(e);
                dataAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }
    }
```

**ListDetail class**

```
public class ListDetail extends AppCompatActivity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.list_detail);

    final long id=getIntent().getLongExtra("id",-1);
    String name=getIntent().getStringExtra("name");
    int series=getIntent().getIntExtra("series",-1);
    int reps=getIntent().getIntExtra("reps",-1);
    int weights=getIntent().getIntExtra("weights",-1);

    String notes=getIntent().getStringExtra("notes");
    TextView txtName=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.detail_name);
    TextView txtSeries=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.detail_series);
    TextView txtReps=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.detail_reps);
    TextView txtWeights=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.detail_weights);
    TextView txtNotes=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.detail_notes);

    txtName.setText(name);
    txtSeries.setText(Integer.toString(series));
    txtReps.setText(Integer.toString(reps));
    txtWeights.setText(Integer.toString(weights));
    txtNotes.setText(notes);

    Button btnDelete=(Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_delete);
    btnDelete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
            Intent intent=new Intent();
            intent.putExtra("id",id);
            setResult(RESULT_OK,intent);
            finish();
        }
    });

}
```

Thanks in advice for any help, I hope it would be easy :)

Comment: Probably ur fragments on activity result is not called. U should redirect from the activity's on activity result that contains the fragment

Comment: Sorry, I don't get it. Can u give me sample code?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17061844/5923606

Comment: I solved that problem by changing id type to int. Don't why Long wasn't working. Anyway thank you for your help!